# CMS for rails 2 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently working on a 7 year old project which is running on Rails 2.3.  Are there any CMS's similar to Refinery CMS or Active Admin that still run on this version of Rails?

I'd prefer to use a gem like Refinery or Active Admin rather than creating one myself.

Answer (score 0):

We've used [RadiantCMS](https://github.com/radiant/radiant) in our 2.3.x Rails apps, give that a try.

Comment: Do they still support rails 2.3

Comment: Yes. Version 1.1.2 has a dependancy on Rails 2.3.16. See [here](https://github.com/radiant/radiant/blob/1.1.2/Gemfile)